# How can you programmatically make the "mouseover" item into the selected item in a tree/list?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, tree, focus

I would like to programmatically change a selected item, in a tree or list, to the item currently "marked/focused" under the mouse pointer .
I'm working with an Flex Air standalone application.

I was thinking in the lines of:
myTree.selectedItem = EVENT.TARGET (where EVENT could be a mouseover/rightclick/rollOver event, and TARGET should be the node/item currently under the mouse pointer).

Is there a way of doing this (or in any other way)?

Ahh, and i want to do it without left clicking ;-)

Thank you in advance,
Sebastian

Comment: Welcome at SO! Some more effort would be appreciated from your side. I think you are going in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I found this interesting enough so I am asking if this is the easiest way to achieve this. First off, instead of the list, you need to add the rollOver-listener to the ItemRenderer, not to the list itself (as the event.target and event.currentTarget will just show your list).

So lets create a custom ItemRenderer and add a rollOver listener

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
            autoDrawBackground="true" height="20" rollOver="itemrenderer1_rollOverHandler(event)">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        protected function itemrenderer1_rollOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.SELECT_ITEM, data, true));

        }

    ]]>

    <s:Label id="label1" text="{data.label}"/>

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

You need to somehow get the value of the selected item (which is the data on the itemRenderer) so I created a CustomEvent-class just to do so.

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class CustomEvent extends Event
    {

        public var selectedItem:Object;

        public static const SELECT_ITEM:String = "selectItem";


         public function CustomEvent(type:String, selectedItem:Object, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false)
         {
            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
            this.selectedItem = selectedItem;
         }
    }
}
```

then I added a eventListener to the main class and set the list.selectedItem property accordingly:

```
//for the main MXML initializer: 
    this.addEventListener(CustomEvent.SELECT_ITEM, rollOverChangeSelected);


            //and the function:
    protected function rollOverChangeSelected(ce:CustomEvent):void{


            list.selectedItem = ce.selectedItem;

    }
```

**Another way**: bindable variable
The list:

```
s:List id="list" allowMultipleSelection="true"  selectionColor="red" rollOverColor="red" itemRenderer="customItemRenderer" selectedItem="{_rollOverSelectedItem}">
```

The variable and set / get methods:

```
        [Bindable] public var _rollOverSelectedItem:Object;     

        public function get rollOverSelectedItem():Object
        {
            return _rollOverSelectedItem;
        }

        public function set rollOverSelectedItem(value:Object):void
        {
            _rollOverSelectedItem = value;
        }
```

and the ItemRenderer's rollOver-method:

```
protected function itemrenderer1_rollOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            this.parentApplication.rollOverSelectedItem = data;             

        }
```

What is the best/proper way?